# Page reload itself after submitting in ASP MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I have 2 views :

Index : Contains a DropDownList 'Gamme' and a button ' Configurer'

Gestion : Partail View that contains many other fields ,,,I will notice only the necessary which are : DropDownLIst 'Poste' and a button submit 'Enregistrer'

When I click in the button ' Configurer' ,,,the partial view 'Gestion' id opened like this :
[image]

When I fill the fields then I click on the button 'Enregistrer'. All the values will be saved in a list 'ListG'.

The item selected in the DropDownList 'Poste' will be removed.

***Problem :***

After the submitting and removing the item from the DropDownList, I want that the 'Partial view' still displaying and I don't have to click another time on the button 'Configurer'.

Code of Index View :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication2.Models.FlowViewModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Helpers" %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "ProfileGa"))
   { %>

  <div><%:Html.Label("Gamme :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedProfile_Ga, new SelectList(Model.Profile_GaItems, "ID_Gamme", "ID_Gamme"), new { @id = "gg" })%>
  <input type="button" value="Configurer" id="btnShowGestion" onclick="GamDis()"/>

<div id="divGestion">
   <%: Html.Partial("Gestion", Model) %>
   </div>

       <% } %>
input type="button" value = "Valider" />
 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {

         $('#btnShowGestion').click(function () { $('#divGestion').slideToggle("slow") });

     });

</script>
```

Code of the view 'Gestion':

```
 <legend>Gestion de Gamme</legend>

        <div>
        <%:Html.Label("Poste :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedPoste, Model.PostesItems, new { @id = "poste" })%>
<div>
         <%:Html.Label("Nombre de Passage :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Nbr_Passage)%>
         </div>
         <div class="editor-field">
          <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nbr_Passage)%>
          </div>

        <div>
        <%:Html.Label("Position :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Position)%>
        </div>
      <div>
        <%:Html.Label("Poste Suivant :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PosteSuivantSelected, Model.PostesItems, new { @id = "dd" })%>
        <input type="button" value="Ajouter" id="add"  onclick="addtext()"/>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnSave').click(function () {
            $('#poste option:selected').remove();

        });
    });
</script>

        <% } %>
```

a part of the code of the Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
       {   
            var viewModel = new FlowViewModel();
            viewModel.PostesItems = new SelectList(db.Postes.ToList(), "ID_Poste", "ID_Poste");
            viewModel.Profile_GaItems = db.Profil_Gas.ToList();
            viewModel.GaItems = db.Gammes.ToList();
            viewModel.ListG = (List<Gamme>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["GammeList"];

            string[] PostesID;

          if(viewModel.ListG  != null){

           PostesID = viewModel.ListG.Select(item=>item.ID_Poste).ToArray();


          viewModel.PostesItems = new SelectList(db.Postes.Where(item=>!PostesID.Contains(item.ID_Poste)  ).ToList(), "ID_Poste", "ID_Poste");

            }
            return View(viewModel);

        }

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(FlowViewModel model)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("" + model.Nbr_Passage);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                Gamme G = new Gamme();
                G.ID_Gamme = model.SelectedProfile_Ga;
                G.ID_Poste = model.SelectedPoste;

                G.Next_Posts = model.PosteSuivantSelected;
                G.Nbr_Passage = int.Parse(model.Nbr_Passage);
                G.Position = int.Parse(model.Position);

                ((List<Gamme>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["GammeList"]).Add(G);
                var list = ((List<Gamme>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["GammeList"]);


            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
                   }
```

This is the model FlowViewModel :

```
public class FlowViewModel
    {

        [Key]
        public string IDv { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public SelectList PostesItems { get; set; }

        public List<Profile_Ga> Profile_GaItems { get; set; }
        public List<Gamme> GaItems { get; set; }
        public List<Famille> FaItems { get; set; }
        public List<Sous_Famille> SFItems { get; set; }
        public List<Produit> PItems { get; set; }
        public List<Ns_AFaire> NSItems { get; set; }
        public List<Fonction_Poste> FPItems { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public SelectList NextPS { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public SelectList GenreItems { get; set; }
        public string SelectedProfile_Ga { get; set; }
        public string SelectedPoste { get; set; }
        public string SelectedFonction { get; set; }
        public string PostePrecedentSelected { get; set; } 
        public string PosteSuivantSelected { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public string  Nbr_Passage { get; set; }
        public string SelectedGenre { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public List<Gamme> ListG {get;set;}

        public FlowViewModel()
        {
            FaItems = new List<Famille>();
            SFItems = new List<Sous_Famille>();
        }


            public List<string> ID_Fonction { get; set; }


    }
```

Is there any idea to use Session in order to resolve this problem.

Comment: is `divGestion` hidden by default.

Comment: @saravanan you mean when I open the page, if that, yes,,,divGestion is hidden

Answer (score 1):

You can show the partial view if the session has some values like the code shown below

```
var sessionList = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["GammeList"] as List<Gamme>;
if(sessionList != null && sessionList.Count > 0){
   <div id="divGestion">
       <%: Html.Partial("Gestion", Model) %>
   </div>
}
```

Comment: thx ,,,but how can I put this code in the controller,,,it contains a html div ?

Comment: do you mean the reference to `Gamme`. may be you are missing the `<%@ imports Namespace="" %>` in the `index.aspx` page.

Comment: I don't know ! <Gamme> it's underlined in Red and when I put the mouse on it, it said : The type or namespace 'Gamme' coulnd not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly refrence ?)
I will edit my question to add the head of 'index.aspx' and the model
Please check it,,Thanks :)